# Sum of columns over threshold in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I'm trying to sum a bunch of columns in pandas and check whether that sum is over 100 or not.

I already have the sum part sorted, what I'm trying to find is a way to compare each value of the sum to a scalar.

Here's my first attempt:

`df[[col1,col2]].sum(axis=1) > 100.0`

this gave back ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

I've tried with a.any and a.all, but they both return only true or false, so that doesn't work. I've also tried creating a pandas series with the value, but it gives error too.

Comment: Can you post the full code you tried? Your expression will return an array of boolean values, not a single boolean.

Comment: The idea is basically that, what I want to know is how to compare that array to the threshold

Comment: What do you want to compare the boolean array to?

Comment: I want the sum of the columns compared to 100, if any row in the sum is over 100 then I'll raise an error

Comment: Does this work: `if (df[[col1,col2]].sum(axis=1) > 100.0).any():`?

Comment: I've tried something similar (`if df[[col1,col2]].sum(axis=1).any() > 100.0`) and that didn't work, I'll try that share the results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253329/discussion-between-david-siret-marques-and-dogbert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

`(df[[col1,col2]].sum(axis=1) > 100.0).any()`

returns true if any row in the sum is over 100 and False otherwise

Thanks to [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert) for providing this answer in the comments